# Limit Question in Vectorspace with induced norm

Tags: real-analysis

I found this question in a Collection of a Real Analysis Exercises.And i'm having struggles to understand the problem.

Let X be a Vectorspace together with a scalarproduct $\left< .,. \right> :X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb R\quad $ and the norm $\left\| \sqrt { \left< x,x \right>  }  \right\| $. If ${ x }_{ n }\epsilon X$ and $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left\| { x }_{ n } \right\|  } =\rho $

than 
we have $\lim _{ n,m\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sup\quad \left\| { x }_{ n }-{ x }_{ m } \right\|  } =0$ or $\lim _{ n,m\rightarrow \infty  }{ \inf\quad \left\| { x }_{ n }+{ x }_{ m } \right\|  } <2\rho $

I dont get how the assumtions that are given should leado to those restults which is making it ahrd to begin the proof. Could somehown help me to understand the situation and maybe give a hint on how to start the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typed $\epsilon$ instead of $\rho$. The result is an easy consequence of parallelogram identity: $\|x_n-y_n\|^{2}=2\|x_n\|^{2}+2\|y_n\|^{2}-\|x_n+y_n\|^{2}$. Suppose $\lim \inf \|x_n+y_n\| \geq 2\rho$. Then the inequality gives $\lim \sup\|x_n-y_n\|^{2} \leq 2\rho ^{2} +2\rho^{2}-4\rho^{2}=0$ so $\|x_n-y_n\| \to 0$.